# Laravel: Event Listener, getinsertid

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am having trouble implementing Laravel's Event Listener to getinsertid of the last title I saved into my db.  I want to send out a email to the user every time they insert a title into my db with the {id} of the record.  I don't think I'm returning the {id} properly from the create() function.

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::except('_token');

    $this->title->create($input);

            $input['email'] = $email;  
            $this->mailer->sendMail($email, $id);
    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.created successfully') );
}


public function create(array $input)
    {
        foreach ($input as $k => $v)
        {
            $this->title->$k = $v;
        }

        $this->title->save();

           return $id = $title->id;

        Event::fire('Titles.Created', array($this->title, Carbon::now()));
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell us where these methods are located: store() in controller, create() in model? Also what is $this->title(), a model, a repository?

Comment: $this->title is a model

Answer (score 0):

The are some obvious problems such as:

- event not being fired until after the create method has returned
- store() method trying to pass an $id that's not been set
- create() trying to set $id to be $title->id when $title hasn't been set

However, it's difficult to be sure how to correct these problems without some information about where these methods are located in your application and how they each relate to $this->title.